# R - Creating a function from a string

Tags: r, expression

I came across the function below in the [Parlist section of the Expressions chapter in Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#pairlists):

```
make_function <- function(args, body, env = parent.frame()) {
  args <- as.pairlist(args)

  eval(call("function", args, body), env)
}
```

The function allows the user to construct a function from its component pieces: a list of formal arguments, a body, and an environment. E.g.

```
add <- make_function(alist(a = 1, b = 2), quote(a + b))
add
function (a = 1, b = 2) 
a + b

class(add)
[1] "function"
```

**I was wondering if the function could be modified so as to allow the user to input a string for the `body` argument?** I have tried `parse(text = 'a + b')` but this returns an `expression` rather than a `call` as in `quote(a + b)`:

```
class(quote(a + b))
[1] "call"
class(parse(text = 'x^m'))
[1] "expression"
```

Is there a way to construct a `call` object from a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally avoid parsing arbitrary string input from users. Usually, this can be avoided by appropriate software design.

Anyway, just extract the language from the expression:

```
make_function(alist(a = 1, b = 2), parse(text = 'a^b')[[1]])
```

**Edit:**

Just to show how you can check against a whitelist (no regex involved):

```
whitelist <- c("+", "*", "-", "/", "^", "**", "%%", "%/%", "sin", "cos", "tan", "abs") #etc.
expr <- parse(text = "cos(x)^sin(x)*abs(x)")
foo <- function(e) if (length(e) > 1) lapply(as.list(e), foo) else return(e)
funs <- unlist(foo(expr[[1]]))
funs <- funs[vapply(funs, function(x) {x <- eval(x); is.function(x) | is.primitive(x)}, FUN.VALUE = TRUE)]
all(vapply(funs, function(x) as.character(x) %in% whitelist, FUN.VALUE = TRUE))
```

Parsing and evaluating arbitrary code in a public shiny app is a security risk. This check ensures that only a predefined set of functions can be used. If you don't shy away from smaller risks, you could just use a blacklist instead (prohibiting functions like `system`, `system2`, `shell` etc.).

Comment: Thank you @Roland. I agree, however, I have a Shiny app which allows the user to create their own function by inputing an expression, e.g. `'x^n'`, into a `textInput` in the GUI. So I thought I could use something similar to `make_function` in the app's server to convert the string input from the user into a `function` object. Is there a safer alternative to `make_function` in this case? Also, when you say to avoid parsing arbitrary string input, are you implying that `quote(a + b)` is preferred to `parse(text = 'a^b')`?

Comment: I'd really appreciate your input as I've always been wary of using `parse()`. As Prof. Lumley says, "If the answer is parse() you should usually
rethink the question", but other than not allowing the user to create their own function, I can't think of any alternatives.

Comment: Especially for a shiny app, I'd want to at least sanitize and check the user input before evaluation. One way of doing that could be to extract all functions from the parsed expression and compare against a white-list of functions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Yes, I had planned to modify `make_function` to include some checks to that effect, such as using regex to check for any unallowed characters or operators, would something like this suffice? I hadn't thought about creating a white-list though, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: On second thoughts, regex probably isn't the best option. Since the user can specify any mathematical expression, would it be better just to create the function with 'make_function' and *then* use `tryCatch` to test if the expression is valid?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain that so thoroughly @Roland. It hadn't occurred to me that there might be security issues! I am teaching myself how to programme and don't have any collaborators on the project I am working on, so your explanation has helped me out immensely.